# UnsatisfiedResolutionException thrown when using Spring Data Elasticsearch in CDI

Tags: elasticsearch, cdi, spring-data-elasticsearch

I followed the Spring Data Elasticsearch [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.cdi) with regard to the CDI integration in order to use Elasticsearch repositories in a CDI environment.

In short I have imported the related dependencies with Maven and tried to make available the ElasticsearchOperations as a bean.

The result is an UnsatisfiedResolutionException thrown by the 
ElasticsearchRepositoryExtension when trying to initialize potentional Elasticsearch repositories. Probably the ElasticsearchOperations bean is not initialized prior to the execution of the ElasticsearchRepositoryExtension.

Is this a bug or a misconfiguration?

- JDK 8
- Java EE 7
- Wildfly 8.1.0

**Maven dependency**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

**Java code**

```
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public ElasticsearchOperations createElasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().local(true).node().client());
    }
```

**Stacktrace**

```
11:13:32,658 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS015860: Redeploy of deployment "application.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.cdi.ElasticsearchRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(ElasticsearchRepositoryExtension.java:76)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.cdi.ElasticsearchRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(ElasticsearchRepositoryExtension.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:125)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:128)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:102)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:35)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:55)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:372)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:79)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:92)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the class containing your producer method have a bean-defining annotation (e.g. `@Dependent`)? If not, the producer method will be ignored by CDI 1.1.

Comment: No, the class is not annotated with any annotation. I tried to  annotate it with the @Dependent scope and the result is the same. But why is that  necessary since what I want is to expose as bean  the return type of the producer method and not the class?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research myself and have found what is going wrong.

The `ElasticsearchOperations` bean is picked from CDI(actually from the Elasticsearch CDI extension) and put in a map with key the bean qualifiers (by default `@Any` and `@Default`). The problem here is that the `toString()` method is called before setting the key which makes the order of the qualifiers to be hardcoded in the key.

At a later stage a repository bean is discovered having the same qualifiers in different order (`@Default` and `@Any`). Thus, it is impossible to get the `ElasticsearchOperations` from the map in order to associate it with the repository.

I managed to overcome this problem by setting a custom qualifier in both the repository and the `ElasticsearchOperations` producer method. By doing so the order of the qualifiers is the same now.
But then another issue occured...

Its time to mention that I also use the Spring Data JPA and the respective CDI extension. The problem now is that both extension process each repository bean (regardless of what Repostiory interface they implement) resulting in registering the same bean twice which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data CDI extensions are all broken because of a weld bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2185

Weld uses ArraySet to store qualifiers in a Bean. Extensions that store qualifiers to a Bean and register custom Bean instances based on ProcessAnnotatedType with qualifiers are no longer able to use simple matching to obtain the Bean by its qualifiers.

I have fixed it temporarily by changing the way all qualifiers are set in the CdiRepositoryExtension class.

```
                Set<Annotation> qualifiers = bean.getQualifiers().stream()
                    .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.hashCode(),
                            e2.hashCode())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

For Spring Data Couchbase the full code is available here: https://github.com/ldoguin/wildfly-quickstart-spring-data/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/repository/cdi/CouchbaseRepositoryExtension.java